# How to change the default "Loading... " message when the Dash component page is in loading state?

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I tried the `DCC Loading component` and also tried the `CSS` way of disabling the default "Loading.. " text on screen when component is in loading state. It is not working at all. Please suggest me a way to change the default loading message to a loader with `CSS` in `Plotly's Dash`.

This is the `dashapp.py` file that will be loaded as login page:

```
from dash import Dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html 
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from config import appserver
import time

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.YETI,'./frontend/static/stylesheet.css']

dashapp = Dash(__name__, server = appserver,external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,\
url_base_pathname='/application/', title='Home Page', assets_url_path='assets')

dashapp.css.config.serve_locally = True

dashapp.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Hi Welcome to Dash-Flask integration app!'),
], id="child-process")

if __name__=='__main__':
    dashapp.run_server(debug=True)
```

The `CSS` stylesheet is present in directory: `./frontend/static/`. 
I used the `CSS` stylesheet for overwriting the default loading behaviour like this:

```
*[data-dash-is-loading="true"]{
  visibility: hidden;
}
*[data-dash-is-loading="true"]::before{
  content: "Loading...";
  display: inline-block;
  color: magenta;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code yo have that was using the loading component?

Comment: Please check the code i uploaded. One is ```py``` file and another one is ```CSS``` stylesheet.

Comment: What happens if you change the second `visibility: visible;` to `hidden` instead?

Comment: As per the docs, they have given that it would supress the ```loading...``` text

Comment: Looks like an open issue: https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/736

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By adding the below CSS file under `/assets/style.css` directory, issue was resolved for me.

```
/* assets/style.css */
._dash-loading {
  margin: auto;
  color: transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

._dash-loading::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  color: black;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  border: 0.25em solid currentColor;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-border 0.75s linear infinite;
  animation: spinner-border 0.75s linear infinite;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```